# Manage Program Flow with Tasks or Events

Tags: c#, multithreading

My program executes other programs remotely using a service that does not implement change or complete notification.  To determine if the program is complete there is a background thread that runs an infinite loop (until the cancellation token is passed). When a job is submitted it is added to a list of active jobs in the status queue and the background thread checks the status of each job in the list and fires an event with a job as arguments when it completes and another event when the queue is empty.

While this solution does work, I wonder if this is the best possible solution for this problem.  It seems to me that tasks are ideally suited for this situation because they are what I would use if I wasn't relying on the server to dispatch the job.

Is there an advantage to using tasks instead of events in this case?

Comment: Does your program work as a service/daemon receiving jobs to execute or as an ordinary application that starts jobs from the list, waits for completion and exits?

Comment: This program is an ordinary desktop application that queries a database to get a list of files and transforms it into actions to perform on those files and submits those jobs to a server that distributes the work. It does not monitor for changes to the database, but it runs on a schedule.  It needs to support graceful cancellation (do not add to the queue and wait for the queue to empty before exiting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### About asynchronous programming patterns

> Is there an advantage to using tasks instead of events in this case?

I think Tasks may make this particular code clearer.  You're implementing asynchronous operation — submit job and wait it to complete.  There are different patterns for that kind of operations, they're called Asynchronous Programming Patterns.

Tasks or Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP) is the most recent asynchronous programming pattern.  The others patterns are Asynchronous Programming Model (APM) and Event-based Asynchronous Pattern (EAP).  Currently you're using EAP and it is about events.  APM is the pattern where you have `BeginOperation` and `EndOperation` methods.

See this page about [Asynchronous Programming Patterns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152938(v=vs.110).aspx).  It says that EAP and APM is no longer recommended for new development and TAP is the recommended pattern.

I agree with these recommendations, I already forgot when I used events or `Begin/End` methods in my code.  It doesn't mean that TAP should be used everywhere, EAP or APM may fit better in some situations but in your particular situation TAP may be the best choice.

#### How it could be implemented with TAP

We need a `Task` for each job which we will `await`.  So the top-level code will be something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MainAsync(args).Wait();
}

static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
{
    // creating Enumerable of jobs
    // ...
    IEnumerable<Task> tasks = jobs.Select(job => client.SubmitJob(job));
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

`client.SubmitJob` returns `Task`.  It could be implemented with `TaskCompletionSource`:

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
var jobInfo = new JobInfo {Job = job, TaskCompletionSource = tcs};
activeJobs.Add(jobInfo);
return tcs.Task;
```

`TaskCompletionSource` for `Task` is just like `CancellationTokenSource` for `CancellationToken`.  We set `Task` to finish state with `taskCompletionSource.SetResult()` call.  So we keep track of all active jobs with assigned `TaskCompletionSource` and the background thread calls `SetResult`:

```
// ... in the backgroung thread
// ... when the job is completed
jobInfo.TaskCompletionSource.SetResult(null);
```

It would be the same code as for events, you just need to keep the list of `TaskCompletionSource` for each job and call `SetResult` instead of trigger the event.

You can read the details about TAP such as exception and timeout handling [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx) or download a great document about TAP [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957).

#### Further adventures

In the document you can find interesting method called `Interleaved` which you may want to use.  It allows processing an `IEnumerable<Task>` in the order of completion — which tasks completes first will be returned first.

You can return `Task<Job>` from `SumbitJob` method and call `SetResult(job)` in the background thread.  Then you can do this:

```
IEnumerable<Task<Job>> tasks = jobs.Select(job => client.SubmitJob(job));
IEnumerable<Task<Job>> interleaved = Interleaved(tasks);
foreach (var task in interleaved)
{
    Job job = await task;
    Console.WriteLine($"Job {job.Title} is completed");
}
```

The jobs will be reported as they completes.

Comment: The answer with the interleaved approach is unclear regarding how to get Task<Job>.

Comment: My current solution creates a job object, and that object has a field for TaskCompletionSource. When the job is submitted to the server and the monitor finds that it is complete is sets the task result to 0. In the main application I created loop while (jobTasks.Any() { var task = await Task.WhenAny(jobTasks.Select(x => x.tcs.Task)); } This will block until any task is complete and then find the task using the result. Interleave sounds better but I can't figure out the definition for Task<Job>

Comment: @Adam You already have `Task<Job>` for each job from field of type `TaskCompletionSource` and you have `IEnumerable<Task<Job>>` from `jobTasks.Select(x => x.tcs.Task)`.  `Task.WhenAny` waits for completion of any single job, I think it is not what you need.  Try to call `Interleaved` instead of `Task.WhenAny` as in the last code block in the answer.

Comment: I don't have IEnumerable<Task<Job>> I have IEnumerable<Job> where TaskCompletionSource is a property of Job. I couldn't figure out how to make it Task<Job> using TaskCompletionSource

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample solution following the selected answer

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        Task.Run(() => JobMonitor.Start());
        MainAsync().Wait();
    }

    public async Task MainAsync()
    {
        var test = new string[2];
        var jobs = test.Select(x => randomTask());
        var tasks = jobs.Select(x => x.TCS.Task);
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);        
    }

    public Job randomTask()
    {
        var job = new Job();
        job.Submit();
        job.TCS.Task.ContinueWith(task => WelcomeTitle += "\n" + DateTime.Now, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        return job;
    } 
}

public class Job
{
    public TaskCompletionSource<object> TCS = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

    public readonly DateTime Expires;
    public bool IsExpired
    {
        get
        {
            var ret = Expires < DateTime.Now;
            return ret;
        }
    }

    public Job()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
        var num = rnd.Next(1, 20);
        Expires = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(num);
    }

    internal void Submit()
    {
        JobMonitor.SubmitJob(this);
    }
}

class JobMonitor
{
    public static List<Job> activeJobs = new List<Job>();
    private static object _lock = new object();
    public static void SubmitJob(Job job)
    {
        lock(_lock)
        {
            activeJobs.Add(job);
        }
    }

    public static void Start()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                var expired = activeJobs.Where(job => job.IsExpired).ToList();
                foreach (var job in expired)
                {
                    job.TCS.SetResult(null);
                    activeJobs.Remove(job);
                }
            }

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

        }
    }
}
```